# assign multiple commands to the same key binding in ST2

Tags: sublimetext2

I have "Super+Alt+left" to set the layout so that the left pane is wider (66%) of the screen:

[image: current ST2 layout]

I would also like the same key stroke to focus on the left tab so that I can start typing immediately without a click or Ctrl + 0.

Here's what I tried. I added a new plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ExpandAndFocusLeftPane(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    self.view.run_command("focus_group", "args": {"group": 0})
    self.view.run_command("set_layout", "args": {
       "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0],
      "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
      "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
      })
```

And I bound "Super+Alt+Left" to this new command.

```
{
  "keys": ["super+alt+left"],
  "command": "expand_and_focus_left_pane",
  "args":
  {
    "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0],
    "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
    "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
  }
},
```

But it still does not do what i want it to do. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you seeing any effect from this key combination at all? Double-check your `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` files (both Default and User) to make sure you haven't assigned this combo anywhere else.

Comment: yes, I am seeing effect from this key binding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to check if the "focus_group" and "set_layout" commands work as expected.
Open the console (View->Show Console) and try this:

```
view.run_command("focus_group", "args": {"group": 0})
```

You'll get a:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    view.run_command("focus_group", "args": {"group": 0})
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you change it to

```
view.run_command("focus_group", {"group": 0})
```

it won't work. That's because "focus_group" and "set_layout" are `window` commands, so this will work:

```
window.run_command("focus_group", {"group": 0})
window.run_command("set_layout", { "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0], "rows": [0.0, 1.0],  "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]] })
```

So your plugin should extend `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` and use `self.window`:

```
class ExpandAndFocusLeftPaneCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("focus_group", {"group": 0})
        self.window.run_command("set_layout", {
           "cols": [0.0, 0.66, 1.0],
          "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
          "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
        })
```

And `ExpandAndFocusLeftPane` should be `ExpandAndFocusLeftPaneCommand`.

Comment: What name should I use to save the plugin file? In which directory? Is there a convention?

Comment: And finally, how do I set up the Key binding for this command?

Comment: @gprasant `{ "keys": ["super+alt+left"], "command": "expand_and_focus_left_pane" }` should work. You can test it using `window.run_command("expand_and_focus_left_pane")`

Comment: @gprasant Go to Preferences->Browse Packages, and there create a directory (eg: ExpandPane) and put the plugin file there (make sure it ends with `.py`)